# How to send an e-mail using an HTML form and submit it using Node.js and Gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, gulp

Today I have been working on a very easy HTML contact form which should have the possibility to send out an e-mail using Node.js and Gulp, but I cannot figure out a way to make this work. A relative path to a simple .PHP file isn't the correct way, and it should probably via a HTTP request, but honestly

I don't know how to do this with Gulp. How can I send the form data from a HTML to a Gulp task? Or do I need to use firstly JavaScript to catch the form submit?

See HTML code below:

```
                        <form action="What needs to be here now?" method="POST">
                        <h3 class="title is-4 has-text-centered">Uw onderneming aanmelden</h3>
                        <div class="control-material is-secondary">      
                            <input class="material-input" type="text" required>
                            <span class="material-highlight"></span>
                            <span class="bar"></span>
                            <label>Name *</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-material is-secondary">      
                            <input class="material-input" type="text" required>
                            <span class="material-highlight"></span>
                            <span class="bar"></span>
                            <label>Company name *</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-material is-secondary">      
                            <input class="material-input" type="text" required>
                            <span class="material-highlight"></span>
                            <span class="bar"></span>
                            <label>Phone *</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-material is-secondary">      
                            <input id="email" name="email" class="material-input" type="text" required>
                            <span class="material-highlight"></span>
                            <span class="bar"></span>
                            <label>E-mail *</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submit-wrapper">
                            <button type="submit" class="button button-cta is-bold is-fullwidth btn-align primary-btn raised no-lh">
                                Join
                            </button >
                        </div>
```

Comment: Gulp is a build tool--it is used by developers to automate tasks during the development process. It is very frequently set up to run every time a developer makes a change in a file or set of files. Is that what you mean to do? Or do you mean for this web page to send an e-mail when the user clicks the "Join" button?

Comment: Hi @AndyTaton, thanks for your comment. I would like to send an e-mail when the user clicks on the button yes :)

Comment: Then Gulp is the wrong tool for you. Do you want the e-mail to be sent entirely on the front end by the user, or do you want the form to be submitted to a server, and then for the server to send the e-mail?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It's via a front-end by the user (html). Via the server (smtp) would be enough!

Comment: If you could take the time to tidy up the formatting of your code it would be greatly appreiciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy will depend on whether you want the form to trigger an e-mail on the client side, without any interaction with the server; or whether you want the form to be submitted to a server, and then to have the server send an e-mail.

**Client-side only:**

Your "Join" button could trigger a JavaScript function that prevents the default form submission and instead retrieves the form entries and generates a complex `mailto:` address:

```
function sendEmail() {
  // Write some code that gets form entries
  window.location.href = 'mailto:' + address + '?subject=' + ...;
}
```

(There are [lots of web resources](https://yoast.com/dev-blog/guide-mailto-links/) for learning about complex `mailto:` addresses.) This will cause the user's preferred mail client to open, and will fill the e-mail with the content you've specified. The user hits "Send" in their client, and the e-mail is sent, without any involvement of your server.

**Server-side control:**

There are a variety of ways of doing this, but an easy first way is to use a Node.js package like [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com). Set up your server to receive the multipart form data via a POST request route, and then have your server transform that data into mail content into a `Nodemailer` `transporter.sendMail` command. Unlike the client-side case, you will need to set up a dedicated email sender account--either on your own `smtp` server, or on a service like `gmail`--for your server to use.

Alternately, if you want your server to just act as an intermediary and not send its own emails, you could register with a email API like SendGrid, Mailgun, etc. Your server would then hit their API with the data submitted to your POST route, and they would send the email.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tomorrow!

Comment: Hi @AndyTaton, I am trying to implement SendGrid, but after trying to do a ajax call as is described here: (https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/mail-send/v3-mail-send), I will receive in the console the following error: (Failed to load https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://mywebsite" is therefore not allowed access.).